# Method to paste specific column when in terminal

Tags: shell, perl, sed, awk

I'd like to paste only the third column of data from within the terminal.

I originally have something like:

```
4 SF0086 SF0086
12 SF0087 SF0087
17 TSF141 TSF141
29 TSF070 TSF070
30 TSF028 TSF028   
31 TSF122 TSF122
```

which I copy and paste that into the terminal it becomes on a single line

> 4 SF0086 SF0086   12 SF0087 SF0087   17 TSF141 TSF141   29 TSF070 TSF070   30 TSF028 TSF028   31 TSF122 TSF122

I'd like to get it like:

```
SF0086
SF0087
TSF141
TSF070
TSF028
TSF122
```

I can save the one line (middle) option as a file at that point and then use something like `awk`, `sed` or `perl` or anything available in the common POSIX system is an option, but haven't figured that out. I've also had no luck with the `paste` command and I'm coming to the conclusion `paste` won't be able to do it for me. The data changes (meaning the spacing will change) each time I need to extract the third column. Any data extractor/formatting masters out there?

Comment: The tool you are looking for is 'cut'

Comment: Thanks @Grant I should have guessed. D'oh. I'll hopefully formulate an answer and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked best for me, as I will always have duplicates and the numbering (-f fields) will always change, as well as the fact that my list may be hundreds of fields long, `cut` was not proving to be a valid option.

This is what produced what I wanted:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' data.txt > data_cr.txt && sort data_cr.txt | uniq -d > final.txt
```

Where:

```
sed -e 's/\s\+/\n/g' data.txt > data_cr.txt
```

forces all text, separated by spaces, onto their own line and writes it to a new file data_cr.txt...and

```
sort data_cr.txt | uniq -d > final.txt
```

takes the line by line data and only prints a single copy of any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

'cut' is the command you are looking for.  You specify what delimiter to use (whitespace is the default I believe) and which column you want.  The man page will list all the details.

You will have to make sure it gets pasted with its newlines intact for it to work properly.

Comment: I also think this wont be exactly what I need because I only get the data as a single line, even though I need what was originally in the third column. Thanks again for the thought and pointing me in that direction, though...much appreciated.

Comment: I would simply fix whatever is causing the copy/paste to remove the new lines.

Comment: True. Because it's coming into a shell instance of nano, i should probably use vi and solve that issue the moment I paste from the clipboard which would allow me to use cut.

Comment: Or "cat > temp; cat temp | cut -d\  -f 3", paste text, press Ctrl-D.  There is an extra space after the backslash, it's escaping a space character.